# Exception facing while build project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Hi I have a query when i try build a project i am facing following two errors.

```
Error   11  Could not copy "obj\Debug\SchoolManagementSystem.exe" to "bin\Debug\SchoolManagementSystem.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.    SchoolManagementSystem


Error   12  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\SchoolManagementSystem.exe" to "bin\Debug\SchoolManagementSystem.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\SchoolManagementSystem.exe' because it is being used by another process.    SchoolManagementSystem
```

when i restart visual studio the build is succeed but after two to three builds these again raised. If any one have solution so guid me.

Comment: you are sure, your Application itself is not running ? If you started it manually on Windows-Explorer, or with the "Run "Command in VS; it's running, and cannot be overwritten before it is closed.

Comment: The application is not running from any other source except visual studio.

Comment: It should not be running at all - have you checked in the task manager it is not in the process list ? It says the file is in use, so you have to find out the process using the file. On an exe, it's most likely the file itself. On the console try TaskList, or  `TaskList /M School*`